# Jenkins: Aborting postbuild actions when build is aborted

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy script to cancel a running job (behaves similar to "cancel" in the jenkins gui). I want to abort build in a way that nothing to be executed afterwards.

Using build.doStop() I am able to abort the build steps but aborting the build does not stop executing the post build actions. Is there any way that we can abort the postbuild action as well?

I appreciate any help or suggestions, thanks

Comment: Didi you see build.[getExecutor()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getExecutor()).[interrupt()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Executor.html#interrupt())

Comment: Yes. it behaves the same.Postbuild actions are still executed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a late reply, but better ever than never

Try adding a **Groovy Postbuild** or **Execute a set of scripts (and then in Build Steps select Execute System Groovy Script**) as a **first** post build action. You can use either method, stop() or interrupt().

Nevertheless, the build always finishes as **failed** (couldn't figure out why).
Tested on Jenkins 2.73.1